# Property binding in AspNetCore

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-core

I'm using:

```
return RedirectToAction("GetSchedule", new { requirements = preCheckParams.Requirements, weightValues = preCheckParams.WeightValues});
```

in my aspnetcore app. Next I want to reuse the values I pass to the anonymous object in another action:

```
public IActionResult GetSchedule(List<string> requirements, Dictionary<string, int> weightValues)
```

Strangely, the first value gets bound to the List in GetSchedule action, yet the second object, which is a dictionary, is empty. Are there any special rules regarding dictionaries in such cases?

Comment: If my answer has helped you please mark it as answered

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass classes in the routeValues parameter of RedirectToAction.

RedirectToAction method return value is HTTP 302 (Status302Found) which produces a GET request to the specified action. Which means that all your parameters will be put in URL as query string.

List/Array of strings `requirements` can be passed in URL since it binds to `?requirements=value1&requirements=value2&..` etc in query string, but anything more complex than that cannot be bound, only primitive values.

You have several options that first come to my mind:

1. Serialize object to JSON and pass it as a string. This will result in ugly and confusing URL, but it's least painful way.
2. Use [temporary storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) if you don't require strictly stateless mechanism. Store before the action and retrieve the dictionary when you enter it.
3. If you can retrieve weight values from the backend, you may pass some identifier to query by it.